# Scala case class ignoring import in the Spark shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I hope there is an obvious answer to this question!

I've just upgraded to Spark v2.0 and have an odd problem with the **spark-shell** (Scala 2.11 build).

If I enter the following minimal Scala,

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Crime(caseNumber: String, date: Timestamp, description: String, detail: String, arrest: Boolean)
```

I get the following error,

```
<console>:11: error: not found: type Timestamp
```

If I use the Java **Timestamp** class elsewhere, e.g. in a function, then no errors are generated (as you would expect because of the import).

If I fully qualify and use **java.sql.Timestamp** in the case class it works!

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have the same problem within Zeppelin.  How do you fix it there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just that the Timestamp is not loaded in the case class declaration, to fix this you can:

```
:paste
import java.sql.Timestamp
case class Crime(caseNumber: String, date: Timestamp, description: String, detail: String, arrest: Boolean)
```

or

```
case class Crime(caseNumber: String, date: java.sql.Timestamp, description: String, detail: String, arrest: Boolean)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I did, but it used to work in the 1.6 shell... Do you know what's changed?

Comment: How do you fix this within Zeppelin?