# Spark - Need to fully qualify

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726173/scala-case-class-ignoring-import-in-the-spark-shell), but i don't think there is an answer.

My env: Spark v 2.2.1 and Scala 2.11.8

As shown in the original question, it seems spark-shell needs fully qualified notation

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Crime(
  caseNumber: String, date: Timestamp, 
  description: String, detail: String, 
  arrest: Boolean
)

//<console>:12: error: not found: type Timestamp
//         caseNumber: String, date: Timestamp,
//                                   ^
```

However, if the `Timestamp` is fully qualified, there is no issue

```
case class Crime(
  caseNumber: String, date: java.sql.Timestamp, 
  description: String, detail: String, 
  arrest: Boolean
)

// defined class Crime
```

And even for things like `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` or `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, col}`, `import`ing doesn't work.

Any idea why? and it it possible to avoid the fully qualified notation?

PS: Databricks seems to not impose this constraint.

Comment: Does that mean that it works when you type `date: java.sql.Timestamp`?

Comment: Correct, I modified the question to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working. But same thing is working in normal scala shell. Managed to make it work in **one CLI command**: `import java.sql.Timestamp;case class Crime(caseNumber: String, date: Timestamp, ...)`. Maybe you can try that

Comment: Spark has bug reports for this (e.g. [SPARK-17103](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17103)) but it never seems to have been thoroughly solved. The workaround suggested in the post you referenced (using `:paste`) seems to be the most reasonable one.

Comment: This is a problem with the REPL since Scala 2.11. It works fine if you define your classes in a separate JAR. A workaround is to wrap your case classes in an object: `object Classes {case class...}` and then `import Classes._`. This way won't work for Datasets though. Related issue: [SPARK-18880](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18880?jql=text%20~%20%22shell%20case%20class%22)

Comment: @TzachZohar, Miguel, thank you! Are you aware of any similar work around in Zepplin?